# Why do you need ! for Google Colab?

Tags: bash, nlp

Why does

`!pip install https://github.com/elyase/geotext/archive/master.zip`

work, but not

`pip install https://github.com/elyase/geotext/archive/master.zip`

in Google Colab

Comment: Please change your title.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Colab, to run console command, you need to start with `!`.